# Modify Powerlevel10k zsh prompt

Tags: zsh, zshrc

**Goal:** Remove the ":main" of Powerlevel10k zsh prompt
zsh prompt
[image: zsh prompt]
**Details:**

- Using Powerlevel10k
- No framework manager (such as oh my zsh)

I believe I have to change ~/.p10k.zsh, but not sure what field.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Do you want it to not show the branch name only? i.e. still show staged files, untracked files, etc. or do you want to disable reporting of all .git info?

For the latter, look for LEFT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS (should be near the beginning of the file) -- I used p9k before p10k so it ported some settings over:

```
  # The list of segments shown on the left. Fill it with the most important segments.
  typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_LEFT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS=(
  #  os_icon                 # os identifier
    dir                     # current directory
    vcs                     # git status
    prompt_char             # prompt symbol
  )
```

and comment out `vcs`.

For the former, look for VCS and you can remove the parts where it reports local branches, tags, etc.